# Jittery motion when interpolating movement in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, interpolation

Basically, I have two gun objects on my fps player. The real gun and the gun that the player sees. I have a script on the gun that the player sees to follow the position and rotation of the real gun which is a child of the camera via interpolation.

Rotation is fine, but I get jittery movement with the position of the gun. Here is my smooth move script on the gun that the player sees:

```
public Transform target; //The gun that the player doesn't see
public float moveSpeed = 0.125f;
public float rotateSpeed = 0.125f;

void LateUpdate()
{
    //this is causing the jittery motion
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, moveSpeed);

    //this is very smooth
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, target.rotation, rotateSpeed);
}
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Can you confirm the values of `moveSpeed` and `rotateSpeed` match the ones configured in the Inspector?

Comment: @derHugo yes, they match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Otherwise, I would go with a more sensible Unit for your moveSpeed, something that makes sense in your world e.g. 1 meter, then I would use Time.deltaTime to smooth the movement. If it's too slow or too fast you can tweak the speed unit.

```
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 1f;

void LateUpdate()
{
    var t = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; //< just to highlight

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, t);
}
```

The practical reason for using Time.deltaTime is to help smooth depending on your frame rate, if you get a lower frame the Lerp will then adjust. This common method is also explained [in this answer by Eric5h5 from Unity forum](http://answers.unity.com/answers/14289/view.html).

---

Hmm, I wonder if you really need a Lerp to update the Gun position, if you want to sync both I would just update your `transform.position = target.position` since it's done every frame, they would be in sync.

Adding a lerp would just delay that sync.

The fact that you see a difference between the Quaternion and the Lerp is just that you cannot compare those two speed, I believe the speed you set on a rotation is much faster than the one for the lerp.

Comment: Adding the Lerp is most probably intended as a stabilizer to interpolate and smooth out jittery user/controller Input ;)

Comment: This was meant to smooth out the movement, that's the whole reason for having two seperate guns

Comment: @JOGUA Ok, changed my answer, this is what I'd do then.

Comment: @JOGUA I hope it worked! On Stackoverflow you can actually upvote answers and mark them The correct answer (only if it's the case), this is the best way to say thank you ;)